# Objective C - How to compare string from the console

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-comparison

My code always returns "fail" for the following string comparison using `isEqualToString`. What is the correct way to compare strings coming from the console?

```
char buf[MAX_LENGTH];
fgets(buf, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);

NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:buf];

NSLog(@"You typed %@", s);
NSString *n = @"exit";

if ([n isEqualToString:s]) {
    NSLog(@"success!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"fail");
}
```

Comment: What is the log you got from this NSLog(@"You typed %@", s); ?

Comment: Debugger, breakpoint, check variable contents, debug output... All necessary things to know and a lot faster than the web. Please learn to use them and if you already did, please add what you learned from that into the question.

Comment: the log i got is the value inputted e.g. hello . actually my problem is when t i entered a string to compare even if its correct it always branches to the  NSLog(@"fail");

Answer (score 1):

The result of fgets contains "\n", So you need define your "n" as this:

```
NSString *n = @"exit\n";
```

Or remove the "\n" from "s":

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:buf];
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```